# How to have two remote origins for Git?

Tags: git

Our git server will be local, but we want an server where our local repo is also kept online but only used in a `push` to fashion.

How can one do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add remotes with `git remote add <name> <url>`

You can then push to a remote  with `git push <name> master:master` to push your local master branch to the remote master branch.

When you create a repo with `git clone` the remote is named `origin` but you can create a `public` repository for your online server and push to it with `git push public master:master`